# How can I backup nifi processes when restarting Kuberntes pod?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry, apache-minifi

I have deployed Nifi on Kuberntes using [cetic/helm-nifi](https://github.com/cetic/helm-nifi) helm chart. We are facing a problem, If nifi pod restarts we lost the all processes that we created. Is there any way to keep a backup of the process in nifi canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You might be deploying the helm with default config or you are tweaking any configs also?

i have not used **nifi** but i think enabling the **PVC** config for nifi might resolve your resolve.

https://github.com/cetic/helm-nifi/blob/master/values.yaml#L211

You can enable the **PVC** by changing the `values.yaml` line number.

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
```

if you have already created volumes you can also use it.

Answer (score 0):

Nifi keeps flow definitions in the `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/flow.xml.gz` file in the docker image. It is strongly advised to have `/conf` folder persist .There are lots of `kubernetes` alternatives for this . check [the official document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

[image]

You can also find archives in the `/conf` folder for back-ups